# Access Violation when loading Boost::Serialization text_iarchive in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, serialization, boost, access-violation

All,

I've written code to serialize our API's calls using boost serialization. The saving is being performed on linux and the loading on windows, so I went to a text_?archive to begin with. I am able to easily save and load the archive on linux, however when I switch to windows I get an access violation after I've created the text_iarchive while reading the first struct.

After stepping through the boost code with the debugger I've found the issue.

In "boost/archive/basic_text_iprimitive.hpp" I get the access violation on line 84:

```
template<class T>
void load(T & t)
{
    if(is >> t)
        return;
    boost::serialization::throw_exception(
        archive_exception(archive_exception::input_stream_error)
    );
}
```

Specifically the crash is happening inside of is >> t. I've tried a few things to fix this, but with it being boost code I'd rather not have a solution reliant on modifying their code. The first fix was to add:

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string str;
is >> str;
ss.str(str);
ss >> t;
if ( is )
    return;
boost::serialization::throw_exception(
    archive_exception(archive_exception::input_stream_error));
```

Unfortunately this worked and my program kept running. It is a horrible horrible hack, so I tried something else. The calling function looks like:

```
void load(version_type & t){
    unsigned int v;
    load(v);
    t = version_type(v);
}
```

Fairly benign. I first tried to initialize the unsigned int to 0, but that did nothing. My co-worker then recommended changing the unsigned int to an int [albeit jokingly]. Sure enough it worked. Again this is a change in boost code so I'd rather not keep the fix there.

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce this problem outside of code I can't share. I've been able to make a new Visual Studio project and load the file just fine, so I'm not sure what settings I may have changed that would cause such a problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

*EDIT*

I was able to fix this. I'm still unsure of the cause but the problem stemmed from the way in whichI was calling the serialization code.

What I had was:

```
int main()
{
    struct s;
    std::ifstream infile("output.txt");
    std::ifstream types("types.txt");        

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(infile);

    int type = 0;
    types >> type;

    switch( type )
    {
      case 1:
       ia >> s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Putting the the entirety of "case 1" in its own scope [including declaring the struct] worked like a charm.

Comment: I'd suggest the fix is not a fix. It would appear to be a workaround relying on undefined behaviour. The symptoms more or less spell buffer overrun/stack trashing. (Try running the -unmodified- code under valgrind on linux?)

Comment: Everything was working on linux, but like you said it might be a silent error that the system can recover from. I'll punch it through valgrind [the purpose of this was to run the model through callgrind in a shorter period of time] and report back.